# How to get CMTime from CMTimeRange

Tags: objective-c

I'm new in Objective-C programming. I'm sending CMTimeRange from one view to another, but in another view I need starting time in CMTimeRange in CMTime formate. Anybody know how I can
in first view the time range is.

```
CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, realPlayer.currentTime);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CMTime startTime = timeRange.start`

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct{
CMTime          start;      /*! @field start The start time of the time            range. */
CMTime          duration;   /*! @field duration The duration of the time  range. */
} CMTimeRange;
```

so you can get start time with`CMTimeGetSeconds(timeRange.start)`.